# Running a tkinter GUI using crontab

Tags: python, tkinter, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a simple GUI (created using tkinter) that I want to run at a specific time of day on a Raspberry pi 3. Bellow is the code snippet I used in crontab. I invoked the crontab manager using sudo crontab -e.

```
0 18 * * * cd /home/pi/gui && python3 gui.py
```

For the moment, I can execute the GUI by invoking it directly via the Pi's command line. However, it doesn't work when I try to do it using cron. I also tried to switch to a basic python script (writing to a file) and that worked. Is there a specific weird interaction that I need to be aware of?

My setup: raspberry pi 3, python 3, raspi-screen, tkinter (latest version as far as I know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sudo will run without a tty and display that is why you command won't work.

Try having xvfb installed and use

```
0 18 * * * cd /home/pi/gui && xvfb-run python3 gui.py
```

**Update-1: 22-Jun-18**

If you want to use your actual display then you need to make sure that you use below command

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 python3 gui.py
```

And also make sure the cron is for your user. The default `DISPLAY` is `:0`.

When you have a XServer (GUI display), you cannot just connect to it without an authorization. When system start it creates a file and that location is stored in environment variable XAUTHORITY.

When you run a cron, you have limited environment variables. There is no existing `XAUTHORITY` or `DISPLAY` defined
to be able to connect to display you need. So you need to define every environment variable that would be required by your program

So you define `DISPLAY=:0` to select the default display and you need to set `XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority` to prove that you are authorized to connect to the display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173635/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-simon-marcoux).

Comment: this worked for me adding the path to python: /usr/bin/pýthon3 /path_to_file/my_file.py maybe will help someone this info

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian 10 (buster): the only missing part - in my case - was to inform the cron-job using gtk, which display it has to use, by inserting
`DISPLAY=:0`. I used a bash-script to start the python script using tk; This could be a python script as well.

`@reboot DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/path/to/my/script.sh start`

Useful for debugging:

`@reboot DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/path/to/my/script.sh start >> home/pi/Desktop/cron.log` (in one line)

Using cron as user pi (not as root), it was necessary to place the `cron.log` file in some `/home/pi/...` folder to give writing access for the log-files.

Maybe Raspbian needs some time to setup everything before an applicaiton can be started; I used:

`@reboot sleep 10 && DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/path/to/my/script.sh start`

In place of @reboot the usual cron settings can be used, e.g.:

`*/5  *  *  *  *`(rest of line see above)

for every 5 minutes to start.

Comment: Hi! I still get an error when doing it with your method :

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"

Comment: Usually I am working with a 'headless' environment; i.e. the RPi3 is connected to LAN via Ethernet cable, VNC is enabled in raspisetup and a remote desktop using e.g. VNC or other client shows the screen of the RPi on a PC screen. Maybe your graphic display is connected to some other e.g. :1 or :2. 
Does someone know to figure out the active display number or name?